# Find $n$ with equalities of his divisors

Tags: number-theory

Let for a natural number $n$ be $d_1<d_2<...<d_k$ his divisors, where $d_1=1,d_k=n$. Find all n so that $d_5-d_3=50$ and $11d_5+8d_7=3n$.

From the second eqation I got that $d_{k-6}\le 6$ so from that I got $d_{k-11}\le 1\rightarrow d_{k-11}=1=d_1$ so $k$ should be 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second equation, as $d_5\mid n$, we have $d_5\mid 8d_7$. Similarly, $d_7\mid 11d_5$. Thus, $8d_7 = a d_5$ and $11d_5 = bd_7$. So, $d_5 = \dfrac{8}{a}d_7$, and then $\dfrac{88}{a}d_7 = bd_7$. This means that $a\mid 88$. But since $d_5<d_7$, we must have that $a>8$. So $a\in \{11,22,44,88\}$.

If $a=11$, we have $8d_7 = 11d_5$, which implies $8\mid d_5$ and then $8\mid n$. Since $d_5$ is even and $d_5-d_3=50$, we must have $d_3$ even. And since $1,2,4$ are divisors of $n$, we must have $d_3=4$. But this implies $d_5 = 54$, so $3\mid d_5$ and then $3\mid n$, which is a contradiction since then $d_3$ must be $3$.

If $a=22$, we have $4d_7 = 11d_5$, and we can proceed exactly like in the previous case (notice that we only used that $4\mid d_5$ before).

If $a=44$, we have $2d_7 = 11d_5$, and then $2\mid d_5$, which implies (as before) that $d_3$ is even. Furthermore, $11\mid d_7$ and then $11\mid n$, so $d_3$ is an even number less than $11$. Now, if $d_3=4$, we rule it out like before. If $d_3 = 6$, then $3\mid n$ and then we must have $d_3=3$. If $d_3 = 8$, then $4\mid n$ and since $d_3>4$ it is absurd. If $d_3 = 10$, then $5\mid n$ and since $d_3>5$ it is absurd. Then, we have ruled out this case too.

Finally, $a=88$, and so $d_7 = 11d_5$. Plugging this in the second equation, we have that $33 d_5 = n$. Then, $33(d_3+50) = n$, and looking módulo $d_3$, we must have $d_3\mid 33\times 50 = 2\times 3\times 5\times 11$. If $d_3$ has at least two prime factors, then they would also be divisors of $n$ and then $d_3$ could not be the third one (since the second and the third would be the prime divisors). Then, $d_3\in \{2,3,5,11\}$. Trivially, $d_3\neq 2$ since $1<d_2<d_3$.

If $d_3 = 3$, then $d_5 = 53$ and $n = 33\times 53$. If $d_3 = 5$, then $d_5 = 55$ and $n=33\times 55$, and if $d_3=11$, then $d_5=61$ and $n = 33\times 61$.

We just have to check whether this numbers satisfy the conditions, but this is just looking at its divisors, and I'll leave it to you :P

Comment: The answer is 2013